# Fragment fires NPE when returned

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am using this Fragment to load some data in a ListView from a Server, but it seems like whenever it gets recreated (configuration changed), it fires a NPE, as mProgressContainer is null when setListShown gets called again. I tried using setRetainInstance(true) in onCreate, hoping the data won't get downloaded again everytime configuration changes, but it seems something is not right.
Anyway, even without setRetainInstance(true) - which I do want to use it, I`m sure it should not have this behaviour. To clear things out, this fragment works ok the first time it gets loaded, but if for eg. I change from portrait to landscape, it crashes at this line:

```
onResponse -> setListShown(true);
```

**EDIT**

```
public class CategoriesFragment extends ListFragment implements
    Listener<CategoryParsedHolder>, ErrorListener {

private OnCategorySelectedListener mCallback;

private int mTotalArticles = 0;

private CategoriesAdapter listAdapter;

// The container Activity must implement this interface so the fragment can
// deliver messages
public interface OnCategorySelectedListener {

    /** Called by CategoriesFragment when a list item is selected */
    public void onCategorySelected(long id);
}

private static final String SOME_KEY = "id_key";

private long mId;

public CategoriesFragment() {
}

public static CategoriesFragment newInstance(long id) {

    CategoriesFragment f = new CategoriesFragment();

    // add id
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong(SOME_KEY, id);
    f.setArguments(bundle);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "No id received in CategoriesFragment");
    }

    mId = getArguments().getLong(SOME_KEY);

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if (mCallback != null) {
        mCallback.onCategorySelected(id);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (listAdapter == null) {
        listAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(getActivity());
    }
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    setListShown(false);

    new Handler().post(loadCategoriesForTab);

}

final Runnable loadCategoriesForTab = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (NetworkUtil.hasInternetAccess(W2MApp.getW2MAppContext())) {
            W2MApp.getW2MAppContext()
                    .getApi()
                    .getCategories(mId, CategoriesFragment.this,
                            CategoriesFragment.this);
        } else {
            onErrorResponse(new VolleyError(W2MApp.getW2MAppContext()
                    .getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.error_no_internet_connection)));
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnCategorySelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnCategorySelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallback = null;
}

@Override
public void onResponse(CategoryParsedHolder response) {

    if (response.getCategoriesList() != null)
    {

        listAdapter.updateData(response.getCategoriesList());
        setListShown(true);

    } else {
        // if data is invalid or no data found, call onErrorResponse
        onErrorResponse(new VolleyError(getResources().getString(
                R.string.error_data_not_found)));
    }

}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    setListShownNoAnimation(true);

    // TODO set error page here (Oups...)

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    setListAdapter(null);
    MyVolley.cancelPendingRequestsByTag(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

A part of Error Log is here:

```
01-30 10:39:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(31705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 10:39:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(31705): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
01-30 10:39:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
01-30 10:39:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:280)
01-30 10:39:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListShown(ListFragment.java:258)
01-30 10:39:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at com.example.CategoriesFragment.onResponse(CategoriesFragment.java:147)
01-30 10:39:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(31705):    at com.example.ui.CategoriesFragment.onResponse(CategoriesFragment.java:1)
```

Basicly it tells me, that when I change the configuration, and Fragment gets recreated, it doesn't find the ListView anymore, while trying to show it. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your log, I rewrote this answer.

Your NPE is happening inside of loadAnimation, meaning that it's the passed in activity that is null. This is most likely to be because you get the callback before the fragment was attached to the Activity or after it was detached. I would try registering/unregistering for the callback in onAttach/onDetach and see if that helps.

Comment: I agree with your logical explanation, but as my code shows, I cancel any pending requests in Volley in onDestroy(), so it shouldn't fire any callbacks to non`existing Fragments. I updated my Question with Error Log, if it may help. Also, which part of the code would be required for a full understanding of what is happening? I`d really want to retain the instance of this fragment, so it won't reload data from server when configuration changes.

Comment: Removed old answer and wrote a new one. :-)

Comment: I may not fully understand your new answer, what do you mean by registering / unregistering. Doesn't what I already wrote.. do that?

Comment: I think your latest edit of the post removed some code, so I don't see all of it. If I read the error log correctly, the only null value I can get is the activity. But yes, it looks like you register and unregister correctly. Is it crashing every time, or just every now and then?

Comment: Yes, I changed the code and removed all unnecessary code (tested on this code and got that error), and yes, it crashes all the time when for ie I change orientation throwing the exception I wrote in my Question. From my POV, the code looks like a simple usage of ListFragment and Volley library, with setListShown (true/false) for the loading process simulation, but smth seems to be wrong.

Comment: I don't really see anything very wrong with your code. The error in the error log you posted was about getActivity() returning null. (The erring code is gone after your edit.) Two things that may happen differently than you expect is that your runnable will run on the UI thread and that the setListAdapter(null) has no effect. But I doubt those issues will have anything to do with this problem. Would it be possible to see your code as a whole? Github, perhaps? In that case it would be easier to analyze.